# I created a table with javascript, but the content of the table are in php. How insert this content in table if can't runs php inside js?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I created a table with javascript, but the content of the table are in php.
How insert this content in table if can't runs php inside js?

```js
<script> 

  

    NROW = 10;
    
    body = document.body;
    
    div = document.createElement('div');
    body.appendChild(div);

    table = document.createElement('table'); table.setAttribute('border','1');
    div.appendChild(table);
    
    
    for(j=0;j<NROW;j++){
        tr = document.createElement('tr');
        table.appendChild(tr);

            
            td = document.createElement('td');
            tr.appendChild(td);
      /*HERE IS THE PROBLEM*/
      text = createTextNode(<?php echo 'test'?>);
      
            

            td = document.createElement('td');
            tr.appendChild(td);
            

        
    }



</script>
```

``` fdsklk``

Comment: Are you using .html extension or .php extension for the file?

Comment: using extension .php

Comment: 1.create the page, 2. query your PHP script with ajax, 3. create your table with the ajax response

Comment: would be that XMLHttpRequest() ? I dont know much about it. I'll see it

Answer (score 0):

Just to a record and help others. Following the Kinglish's help above.

I used this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo">
<h1>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h1>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```